# Modals from a stacknavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to launch a modal from a regular stackNav. Any help super appreciated.

I need to launch `AddBook` in a modal from `BooksList`. Here is my stack set up:

```
const BookModalsNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    AddBook: AddBook,
}, {
    mode: 'modal',
}); 

const MyBooksNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    BooksList: BooksList,
    ViewBook: ViewBook,
    BookModalsNavigator: BookModalsNavigator,
});
```

and I cam calling the modal with:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AddBook')
```

and getting this :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across this.. I basically had it upside down. You have to build your routes THROUGH the modal stack. The fix:

```
const MyBooksNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    BooksList: BooksList,
    ViewBook: ViewBook,
});

const BookModalsNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    MyBooksNavigator: MyBooksNavigator,
    AddBook: AddBook,
}, {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
});

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    MyBooks: BookModalsNavigator,
    Capture: Capture,
    More: MoreNavigator,
},
```